# Jquery Scroll text with middle pause

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` with lists (ul, li).

I want a Jquery plugin to do the text scrolling from left faster and pause during few second in the middle of the `<div>`. Then the text scroll to right and disappear.

Do you have plugin names?

Thanks.

**EDIT :** 
After help of mrtsherman, I successful create the script.
There is the solution :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#affichage_titreSemaine > span').css('opacity', '0');

    function TitresSemaine() {
        // get the item that currently has the 'show' class
        var current = $('#affichage_titreSemaine .show');

        var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $('#affichage_titreSemaine span :first');
        // fade out the current item and remove the 'show' class
        current.animate( {opacity: "1.0", marginLeft: 465 - (current.width())/2}, 500, 'swing');
        current.delay(2000).animate( {opacity: "0.0", marginLeft: 930 - current.width()}, 500, 'swing', function(){
            $(this).animate({marginLeft : 0}, 10, 'swing');
            $(this).hide();
            next.addClass("show");
            next.show();
        }).removeClass("show");

        // repeat by calling the textloop method again after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(TitresSemaine,4000);
    }

    TitresSemaine();

});
```

Comment: Is this a horizontally scrolling list? Can you post a link to an example of what you want, or at least something that is similar to what you want? Your description is hard to undestand.

Comment: I will try to find an example, in deed, I've saw that but i forgot the link.
It's an horizontal scroll, like the html <marquee> but it's stop at the middle of the container few seconds and restart.
The text arrives faster from the left side and pause few second in the middle and then go the right and disapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. I don't know of a plugin that does it, but pretty easy to code yourself using animation callbacks.

http://jsfiddle.net/ABaEE/

```
$('span').animate( {marginLeft:0}, 1500, 'swing', function() {
    $(this).delay(2000).animate( {marginLeft:250}, 1500, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Possible to do with infinite loop ? (see my next answer)